# libnss3-nssdb library missing in ubuntu 17.04

Tags: mozilla

I have installed Ubunt 17.04 recently. I tried to install libnss3 libraries. I need libnss3-nssdb, but this library is missing in 17.04. Let me know if any other solutions are possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that `libnss3-nssdb` [is not in the Zesty repo yet](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=zesty&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=libnss3-nssdb). I couldn't find anything on their plans to bring it up, but there is a new [`libnss3-tools`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/libnss3-tools) that may have what you want. Here is how to install the old `libnss3-nssdb` package that you want:

### Graphical Interface Way:

1. Open `Ubuntu Software Center` and click "Software Sources"
   [image: Open <code>Ubuntu Software Center</code> and click "Software Sources"]
2. Click on "Other Software", "Add", and then paste this in `deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main`
   [image: Click on "Other Software", "Add", and then paste this in <code>deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main</code>]
   **Note:** You can also substitute `xenial-updates` for `trusty`, but there are [noted issues with going back that far.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/NSS/NSS_3.29.1_release_notes)
3. Reload `Ubuntu Software Center` or just wait and let it rebuilt its cache, then search for your package (`libnss3-nssdb`) and install it.
   [image: Add package libnss3-nssdb]

### Command Line Way:

To install `libnss3-nssdb` in 17.04, you can add the Xenial Updates source by editing your `/etc/apt/sources.list` to include a line with this `deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main`.

1. Make a backup first `sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.bak`
2. Add in the new line `echo "deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main " | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list`

   **Note:** It is tempting to just do a `echo >>` but that won't work.
3. Update to use the new repo `sudo apt-get update`
4. Install your package `sudo apt-get install libnss3-nssdb`

If you get any error like held broken packages, please do the following. 
`sudo apt-get install libnss3=2.3.26.2-0ubuntu0.16.04.2` and repeat step 4 again.

Comment: Thank you. It did not work. I have tried that already, it shows me unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages. Tried to build from the source code as well, it shows me plarena.h file missing. Hence moved to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS for the moment.

Comment: You can what those are with `dpkg --get-selections | grep hold` but you probably need to open a new question for that issue.

Comment: Found the solution. Combined your idea and used the following 
`sudo apt-get install libnss3=2.3.26.2-0ubuntu0.16.04.2`

Comment: Great! You can post an answer or I can edit it into mine. Also, please accept an answer if it helped you.Thanks!